# git: Can't add files to github

Tags: git, github, addition

I found some similar questions like this. But I can't find a solution.

I add a folder with files and sub-folders to my local repository using:

```
git add .
```

And then with:

```
git commit -m "comment"
```

I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

The problem is, that I can't find the files on github. Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
git push -u git@github.com:kamekame/wolke master
```

gives:

```
To git@github.com:kamekame/wolke
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:kamekame/wolke'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

SOLUTION:

```
git remote -v
```

gives me:

```
origin  git@github.com:kamekame/alpha.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:kamekame/alpha.git (push)
```

which was different from my push adress kamekame/wolke!

Comment: Well, you need to push. commit will only add a commit to your local repository. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Run `git pull` to sync first

Comment: git pull --> Allready up-to-date! This also doesn't help. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your local repo to push upstream to your github repo.
from: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

Your next steps would be:

```
# create repo via github ui or github cli

# add github as the origin
git remote add origin remote_repository_URL

# push changes to repo
git push origin master
```

Comment: git remote add origin https://github.com/kamekame/wolke -->
fatal: remote origin already exists.

Comment: git push origin master --> 
Everything up-to-date

Comment: and you are saying that the files still aren't pushing? check your origin remote by `git remote -v`. if the remote url doesn't look right, you can reset it with `git remote set-url origin url`. also, you should be able to pull without errors if it's setup correctly.